# Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.0.0

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, dependencies

I was trying to create a simple spring boot project with single module and the repository was
mavenCentral(). the dependency I have used in project were literally taken from maven central. I dont understand why its not working, it had worked before.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '3.0.0'
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '3.0.0'

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

this is my buid.gradle.

```
test: Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.0.0.
Required by:
    project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

this is the error I am getting

Comment: Have you tried generating a project from start.spring.io and check that it works? Comparing both should help you pinpoint the difference. Look at the other gradle files as well.